# What can I do to remove bathroom stains?

Tags: bathroom, tile, toilet, cleaning, porcelain

I just moved into this house and I was trying to clean the bathroom tiles and the toilet but there are these stains that won't come off. I've tried bleach and other stuff, I don't know what to do. The stains look like water drippings.

Comment: It depends what they're made of, from rust to limescale... Pictures might help.

Comment: Have to have pics to get any worthwhile answers.  It is possible the stains are from mold or other destructive activity under or behind the tiles.  Good pics will give indications of that.

Comment: Are the stains rough and crusty to the touch? If yes, it's scale.

Answer (score 1):

> The stains look like water drippings.

If, by this, you mean white (sometimes tan/brown) crusty deposits left by water drying where it's dripped, an acid product is the most likely solution. Weaker acids are safer for you, and work more slowly than stronger acids that are more hazardous for you and work faster. With all, but particularly with the stronger ones, be sure to use appropriate personal protective gear, and plenty of ventilation.

White vinegar is probably the most common one you may have handy, which is relatively safe for you in normal concentrations, but definitely needs ventilation anyway as it is quite volatile.

Be aware that acids may cause detrimental effects on metallic fixtures, so limit their application to ceramics needing cleaned.